# Выгружаемый архив поврежден или имеет не верный формат

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Делаю выгрузку архива с бэка.
На фронте его выгружаю, но он битый (не открывается).

Думал как-то не так данные пишу в архив, но нет. Дело не в этом. В примере ниже я помещаю в архив только один текстовый файл. Но и этот архив не открывается.

Также вес архива получается слишком маленьким.
Что делаю не так ?

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("file.txt");
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ms.Length;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Archive.zip"
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
            return response;}
```

UPD. Кусок кода из работы:

```
var setting = Configuration.GetTypedSection<MicroSipSettings>("MicroSip");


        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(setting.DirMicroSip);
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (string filepath in filepaths)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                    var entry = archive.CreateEntry(filename);
                    using (var file = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(setting.DirMicroSip, filename)))
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                    }
                }
                ZipArchiveEntry iniEntry = archive.CreateEntry(setting.NameIni);
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(iniEntry.Open()))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("[Settings]");
                    sw.WriteLine("accountId=1");
                    ...

                }
            }

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Archive.zip"
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: А что у вас в Entry ничего нет? Покажите более реалистичный код.

Comment: не понял, что этот код должен делать. Вернуть пустой MemoryStream?

Comment: @tym32167 по идее нужно вернуть архив. У меня на фронт приезжает какой-то архив, но он битый. Вообще не открывается. Да и вес маловат

Comment: @aepot дополнил пост кодом.
Как это должено по идее работать.
В некой директории settings.DirMicroSip лежат файлы. Эти файлы все  запихиваю в архв. Также создается отдельно ini файл и также ложится в этот же архив.
Архив в свою очередь нужно передать на фронт. Обычно использовал для этого File и FileContentResult  И такой вариант работает. Но сейчас надо вернуть HttpResponseMessage. Вот тут уже что-то не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы уничтожаете `MemoryStream` до того как воспользуетесь им.

То есть вот здесь

```
return response;
```

следом неявно вызывается

```
memoryStream.Dispose();
```

И только после этого `response` долетает до адресата и начинает отдаваться на скачивание. В результате сервер ничего не может прочитать из закрытого потока чтобы отдать клиенту.

Исправьте

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
```

на просто

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
```

Вообще `MemoryStream` можно не диспозить, у него внутри ничего такого нет, что требует обязательного следования правилам работы с `IDisposable`.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ. На самом деле я делал и так и так.
Сначала сделал без using, потом подумал что в этом ошибка и добавил его. И уже не стал убирать.
У меня уже складывается впечатление, что с самим архивом все ок. Просто я не верно его принимаю на фронте т.к. работа с HttpResponseMessage для меня в новинки

Comment: @VadimTregubenko я проверил код, он рабочий. Кроме того что я указал, всё ок.

Comment: @VadimTregubenko хотя вот здесь `iniEntry.Open()` я бы сделал `using`, на всякий случай. Но это вряд-ли на что-то повлияет.

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже это фронт.
У меня качается архив не с контентом который я отправляю, а с json. А если выставить application/zip то и вовсе ничего не грузит. 413 возвращает

Comment: @VadimTregubenko ну тогда проблема за пределами показанного кода, где-то в контроллере, например.